# How can I tell whether the JVM performed a garbage collection?

Tags: java

Rewritten since everybody seems to be answering a different question:

How can I tell whether the JVM performed a garbage collection? Perhaps a `System` listener?

Comment: Modern [Garbage Collection](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) is an ongoing process that is specifically designed to produce the least impact on the application.  Unless you are faced with the problem that is definitely caused by GC I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: try this hack: http://java.dzone.com/articles/letting-garbage-collector-do-c

Comment: it is not good practice to stay dependent on such explicit request of gc

Comment: I've rewritten the question because everybody seems to think I'm trying to force the GC to occur (I'm not!) - I only want to know whether it happened or not.

Comment: Add the argument `-verbose:gc` when starting the program. It will print short information about the garbage collection steps on the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Garbage collection statistics via JMX.  This is how `jstat` gets the information.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    for (GarbageCollectorMXBean bean : ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()) {
        System.out.println(toMap(bean).toString()
                                      .replace("javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType", "ST")
                                      .replace("java.lang.", ""));
    }
}

public static Map<String, Object> toMap(Object o) {
    LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    BeanInfo beanInfo = null;
    try {
        beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(o.getClass());
    } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
        if (propertyDescriptor.getName().equals("class")) continue;
        Object value = null;
        try {
            value = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod().invoke(o);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            value = e.toString();
        }
        map.put(propertyDescriptor.getName(), value);
    }
    return map;
}
```

prints a lot of descriptive information, but hidden in there is all the stats of how many collections have been performed, how long they took and the size of the regions before and after collections.

In particular, you can look at the collectionCount. When this increases, a collection occurred.

{collectionCount=2, collectionTime=1, lastGcInfo=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=sun.management.PS Scavenge.GcInfoCompositeType,items=((itemName=GcThreadCount,itemType=ST(name=Integer)),(itemName=duration,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=endTime,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=id,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=memoryUsageAfterGc,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.TabularType(name=Map,rowType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=Map,items=((itemName=key,itemType=ST(name=String)),(itemName=value,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long))))))),indexNames=(key))),(itemName=memoryUsageBeforeGc,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.TabularType(name=Map,rowType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=Map,items=((itemName=key,itemType=ST(name=String)),(itemName=value,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long))))))),indexNames=(key))),(itemName=startTime,itemType=ST(name=Long)))),contents={GcThreadCount=10, duration=1, endTime=40, id=2, memoryUsageAfterGc=javax.management.openmbean.TabularDataSupport(tabularType=javax.management.openmbean.TabularType(name=Map,rowType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=Map,items=((itemName=key,itemType=ST(name=String)),(itemName=value,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long))))))),indexNames=(key)),contents={[Compressed Class Space]=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=Map,items=((itemName=key,itemType=ST(name=String)),(itemName=value,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long))))))),contents={key=Compressed Class Space, value=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long)))),contents={committed=524288, init=0, max=1073741824, used=424552})}), [PS Survivor Space]=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=Map,items=((itemName=key,itemType=ST(name=String)),(itemName=value,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long))))))),contents={key=PS Survivor Space, value=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long)))),contents={committed=524288, init=524288, max=524288, used=507920})}), [PS Old Gen]=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=Map,items=((itemName=key,itemType=ST(name=String)),(itemName=value,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long))))))),contents={key=PS Old Gen, value=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long)))),contents={committed=22544384, init=22544384, max=22544384, used=151568})}), [Metaspace]=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=Map,items=((itemName=key,itemType=ST(name=String)),(itemName=value,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long))))))),contents={key=Metaspace, value=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long)))),contents={committed=4980736, init=0, max=-1, used=3648080})}), [PS Eden Space]=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=Map,items=((itemName=key,itemType=ST(name=String)),(itemName=value,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long))))))),contents={key=PS Eden Space, value=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long)))),contents={committed=1048576, init=524288, max=9961472, used=0})}), [Code Cache]=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=Map,items=((itemName=key,itemType=ST(name=String)),(itemName=value,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long))))))),contents={key=Code Cache, value=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long)))),contents={committed=2555904, init=2555904, max=251658240, used=1242560})})}), memoryUsageBeforeGc=javax.management.openmbean.TabularDataSupport(tabularType=javax.management.openmbean.TabularType(name=Map,rowType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=Map,items=((itemName=key,itemType=ST(name=String)),(itemName=value,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long))))))),indexNames=(key)),contents={[Compressed Class Space]=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=Map,items=((itemName=key,itemType=ST(name=String)),(itemName=value,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long))))))),contents={key=Compressed Class Space, value=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long)))),contents={committed=524288, init=0, max=1073741824, used=424552})}), [PS Survivor Space]=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=Map,items=((itemName=key,itemType=ST(name=String)),(itemName=value,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long))))))),contents={key=PS Survivor Space, value=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long)))),contents={committed=524288, init=524288, max=524288, used=524288})}), [PS Old Gen]=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=Map,items=((itemName=key,itemType=ST(name=String)),(itemName=value,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long))))))),contents={key=PS Old Gen, value=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long)))),contents={committed=22544384, init=22544384, max=22544384, used=8192})}), [Metaspace]=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=Map,items=((itemName=key,itemType=ST(name=String)),(itemName=value,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long))))))),contents={key=Metaspace, value=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long)))),contents={committed=4980736, init=0, max=-1, used=3648080})}), [PS Eden Space]=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=Map,items=((itemName=key,itemType=ST(name=String)),(itemName=value,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long))))))),contents={key=PS Eden Space, value=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long)))),contents={committed=524288, init=524288, max=9961472, used=524288})}), [Code Cache]=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=Map,items=((itemName=key,itemType=ST(name=String)),(itemName=value,itemType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long))))))),contents={key=Code Cache, value=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport(compositeType=javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType(name=management.MemoryUsage,items=((itemName=committed,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=init,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=max,itemType=ST(name=Long)),(itemName=used,itemType=ST(name=Long)))),contents={committed=2555904, init=2555904, max=251658240, used=1242560})})}), startTime=39}), memoryPoolNames=[LString;@6d03e736, name=PS Scavenge, notificationInfo=[Ljavax.management.MBeanNotificationInfo;@568db2f2, objectName=java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=PS Scavenge, valid=true}
{collectionCount=0, collectionTime=0, lastGcInfo=null, memoryPoolNames=[LString;@378bf509, name=PS MarkSweep, notificationInfo=[Ljavax.management.MBeanNotificationInfo;@5fd0d5ae, objectName=java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=PS MarkSweep, valid=true}

Answer (score -1):

GC is hardly going to affect your game performance, because it's ongoing, it keeps collecting everything that isn't used anymore and it does it while the code is running. You can force the GC to work and then put up a loading screen, but that's not recommended.

PS.: If the GC affected the game performance that much, Minecraft would be a disaster and Android apps and games wouldn't be built in Java! Think about that ;)

Comment: I'm not trying to control garbage collection! I just want to know whether it happened or not.

Comment: And what do you mean by *"you can force it"*? I though that the most you can do is *suggest* it to work.

Answer (score -2):

```
System.gc();
```

Java uses managed memory although I would not recommend you to use the above method.

From the Java Docs

> Calling the gc method suggests that the Java Virtual Machine expend
>   effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the memory
>   they currently occupy available for quick reuse. When control returns
>   from the method call, the Java Virtual Machine has made a best effort
>   to reclaim space from all discarded objects.

Comment: Not me, but I don't understand: I asked if there is a way for the JVM to tell me whether a garbage collection happened or not, but the above method is only a suggestion so I wouldn't necessarily know if the GC did work or not.

Comment: It was not me with downvote, to less reputation. BUT. do you have read the question?

Comment: @JustKidding:- I dont think you have to worry about the garbage collection and explicitly call the method as the JVM is smart enough to do it for you!

Comment: @R.T.: But that's not  what I'm asking! I'm not trying to control garbage collection. I just want to know whether it happened or not.

Comment: @JustKidding:- I dont know what you intend but when you start Java with `-XX:+PrintGC`, it will print messages whenever it garbage-collects.

Comment: @JustKidding:- Also you can use `jconsole.exe`, which can be found in the bin directory of your jdk. It shows you a lot of details about your running JVM. Also check this http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/how-to-monitor-java-garbage-collection/

Comment: Nice, can this be checked on runtime? (I mean, from my Java code)

Comment: Yes. See the javadocs under `java.lang.management` for `ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()` which returns List of `GarbageCollectorMXBean`. Note for current Java you should expect 'scavenge' passes to be more frequent and cheap, and (full) 'marksweep` passes to be less frequent and expensive, but next year Oracle may decide to change to a different design.